How do I save an image from excel to folder
I have an excel file containing images, I want to save them in a folder, using python.
I have done this in java in the past, iterating through the images in a sheet and saving them as byte arrays using aspose.cells. Now, due to some issues in code output, I need to do the same through python. Is it possible for me to do this? If yes, how do I do this?
This is the python (converted from java) code I am using -
import openpyxl
wb = load_workbook("myfile.xlsx")
sheet = wb["sheet1"]
header_name = ""
pic_name = ""

if sheet is not None:
   pics = sheet._images
   for pic in pics:
       header_name = ""
       pic_bytes = bytearray(pic)
       if pic.anchor.row - 2 >= 0:
           header_name = sheet.cell(row=pic.anchor.row - 2, column=pic.anchor.col_idx -1).value.strip()
           pic_name = header_name + ".png"
           Mainclass.PicBytes_map_sheet[pic_name] = pic_bytes 


Ditched the use of SheetImageLoader since we want the byte array. 
I have used a dictionary to store the byte array it allows the key to be string and the value to be the bytearray but you could use a hashmap.
import os.path
from io import BytesIO
import string
import openpyxl
from PIL import Image


# Load workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('images.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

# Set path for saved images
images_path = 'images'

hashmap = {}  # Dictionary for storing the image bytearray

# ### Loop to find the images location and copy to the new work book/sheet
for image in ws._images:
    # Get row and column info for the image
    row = image.anchor._from.row
    col = image.anchor._from.col

    # Image name in diagonal opposite cell to the TL of image
    img_name = ws.cell(row=row, column=col).value
    # File name if saving image
    image_file = os.path.join(images_path, f'{img_name}.png')

    print(f"Image '{img_name}' located at: {col}{row+1}")

    # Get image bytes
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(image._data()))

    img.save(image, format='PNG')
    img_bytes = image.getvalue()
 
    # Place image into dictionary with image name as Key
    hashmap[img_name] = img_bytes

    # Save image to file
    img.save(image_file, format='PNG')

print(hashmap)


thank you for the code, can you also let me know how do I access the cell diagonal to the image? This cell contains the image name

just also wanted to know, is it possible for me to save my images as a byte array, like in java, I saved them in a hashmap of string (image name), bytearray (image in bytearray form)

Certainly possible to save the images as a byte array and add into a dictionary with string key and bytearray value. The cell that diagonal to the image, which diagonal, above and to the left? So if the image is in 'B4' the name is in 'A3'?

The image is pasted in the excel sheet, not in a particular cell, and the name is in immediate diagonal upper left cell.

The images may be larger than the cell, but they are considered to be anchored at the cell where the top left corner sits, That is the location cell that the code returns. So as indicated then, if the top left corner of the image is 'B4' then the cell with the name in it is 'A3'...
